# Webview doesnt show Æ Ø Å properly

Tags: html, android, character-encoding, webview, android-webview

I have some content on a webpage which contains æ ø å, but my webview cant show them properly.

Does anyone know what the problem might be ?

Comment: You should accept answers to your previous questions, so that anyone else who has the same question knows what the right answer was. People are more likely to answer if they know that you appreciate the time they've taken

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to use UTF-8 characters inside an (X)HTML page you declare the encoding with this meta tag (in the head section of the page):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

If that alone does not work you may be able to find more useful information [here](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding).

Comment: I had a similar problem, where some Android phones would not display Swedish characters correctly in a site I'm developing. It did not work even though I used the HTML5 version of the meta tag above. When I added a default character-set in the htaccess file, it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure that the HTML file is saved as UTF-8 and that the [`Content-Type`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) header in the HTTP response contains the proper charset. You can verify the headers by among others [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com).

A `<meta>` tag for `Content-Type` would only work when the `Content-Type` header in the response is absent and this is usually **not** the case when the HTML file is served over HTTP. However, its presence is good for offline viewing and self-documentary purposes.